# Android device to GCM message "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"

Tags: android, mysql, xampp, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I have an application that sends messages to GCM.

In my local server I can send both upstream and downstream messages successfully.

But when I deployed my server to the cloud I am getting Access denied for user `'root'@'localhost'` when I send upstream message.

I changed my Android api key to a server Api key but it made no difference.

Since there are multiple layers on the whole thing I don't know where the issue is.

I am able to SSH to my server from my local environment and can see all my mysql databases and tables but I can't access phpmyadmin from my browser.

My Instance in Google compute engine is also running. But I noticed mysql is disabled though.

So I am suspecting maybe that is the cause since the error is thrown from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just I was using development server password. I am the using the right password and I am able to access mysql in my remote server.